# Dataflow job can't be created for several hours

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I submitted a job to Dataflow yesterday and today its status is still "Not started". But when I clicked into the job's title, it first game me a message "The graph is still being analysed" and it returned an error message to the top of the page that said "A job with ID "xxxxxx" doesn't exist".

[image: A screenshot of my Dataflow console]

What I want to do is to remove the job from the list. But it seems I can't perform any actions to the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved.

After I enabled the **Dataflow API**, the job could be successfully run.